# The next page in my UIPageViewController is only loading partially when the page changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController `PageVC` containing 6 view controllers I created in my storyboard. My `PageVC` class is written in Swift.

```
class PageVC: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    lazy var VCArr: [UIViewController] = {
        return [self.VCInstance(name: "OB1"),
                self.VCInstance(name: "OB2"),
                self.VCInstance(name: "OB3"),
                self.VCInstance(name: "OB4"),
                self.VCInstance(name: "OB5"),
                self.VCInstance(name: "OB6")]
    }()

    private func VCInstance(name: String) -> UIViewController {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)

    }

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.delegate = self
        if let OB1 = VCArr.first {
            setViewControllers([OB1], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }

    public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
        guard let viewControllerIndex = VCArr.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }

        let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

        guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
            return VCArr.last
        }

        guard VCArr.count > previousIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        return VCArr[previousIndex]
    }

    public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
        guard let viewControllerIndex = VCArr.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }

        let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1

        guard nextIndex < VCArr.count else {
            return VCArr.first
        }

        guard VCArr.count > nextIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        return VCArr[nextIndex]
    }

    public func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int{

        return VCArr.count

        }

    public func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int{

        guard let OB1 = viewControllers?.first,
            let OB1Index = VCArr.index(of: OB1) else {
                return 0

        }

        return OB1Index
    }

    public func nextPageWithIndex(index: Int)
    {
        let nextVC = VCArr[index]
        setViewControllers([nextVC], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


}
```

In each of the contained view controllers I have buttons that advance to the next index of `PageVC`. Most of the contained view controllers have classes written in Objective-C so I called the next page method like this:

```
-(void)pageNext {

    PageVC *vc = (PageVC *) self.parentViewController;
    [vc nextPageWithIndexWithIndex:2];

}
```

The transition above works great, and `OB3` loads completely. In `OB3` I have an `IBOutlet` to a button that presents my notification permissions dialog with my next page method called in the completion handler like this.

```
- (IBAction)enableBtn:(id)sender {

    UNUserNotificationCenter* center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionSound)
                          completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {

                              [self pageNext];

                              [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"notification"];

                              [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

                              FIRUser *user = [[FIRAuth auth] currentUser];
                              NSString *topic = [@"/topics/ios_user_" stringByAppendingString:user.uid];
                              [[FIRMessaging messaging] subscribeToTopic:topic];

                          }];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

}
```

The page transitions smoothly when I tap "Allow" in the notification permissions dialog, but some of the elements on `OB4` don't load for almost 10 seconds after the transition happens. For example, buttons appear but the text within isn't visible, and neither are `UILabels`. If I wait about 10 seconds they do appear. I've tried rearranging the pages in the `PageVC` index, but no matter which page I use the page always appears partially loaded. There are no animations attached to the elements that aren't loading properly. I think it's something to do with the completion handler in the permissions dialog. How can I make the next page in my `UIPageViewController` load completely upon transition?

Comment: Sounds like you are updating the UI from a non-main thread.  Try putting the `[self pageNext]` inside a dispatch to the main queue: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //update UI in main thread. });`

Comment: That worked!! Thanks so much. If you add your comment as an actual answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: I have added it as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are updating the UI from a non-main thread. Try putting the `[self pageNext]` inside a dispatch to the main queue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //update UI in main thread.
    [self pageNext]
});
```